# Getting an Unknown Attribute error when seeding database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema, rails-migrations

When I seed my database, I get this error: unknown attribute 'user' for Post.

My schema looks like this:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "collection_id"
    t.index ["collection_id"], name: "index_posts_on_collection_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end
```

My seeds.rb file looks like this:

```
require 'faker'

10.times do |user|
  User.create!(
    name: Faker::Name.name,
    birthday: '2019-09-04',
    skin_type: 'Dry',
    email: Faker::Internet.email,
    password:Faker::Internet.password

  )

end
users = User.all
puts "Users seeded"

50.times do
   Post.create!(
     user: users.sample,
     body: Faker::Lorem.paragraphs
   )

end
```

My creating Post migration file looks like this:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :body
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my seeds.rb file, Post.create! cannot access the user attribute. Is this because the user attribute is not included in the CreatePosts migration file? Shouldn't this not matter since within the schema, posts and user_id are connected?

Comment: Do you have user association defined in post? Would you mind sharing the model files?

Comment: @Coco wow I am so dumb.. I forgot to include the belongs_to association in my Post model. Add your comment and I'll make that my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your discussion on the comments, you need to add user association in the post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```